# How to use datareader to get data to textbox from combobox selecteditem

Tags: sql, vb.net, datareader

I have a form with one combobox and textbox.
Now I have a SQL database with a table named `balance`. It has two columns, one is `customername` and the other is `obbalance`.
Now I had bound all the customer name to the combobox.
What I have to do is:
When the user selects a customer name from the combobox, the textbox should show the `obbalance` of the selected `customername`. Here the customer name will not be repeated, only one name with a customer.
What can I do? Please help me.

```
    Dim conectionstring As String
    conectionstring = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SHOPPROJECT\SHOPPROJECT\shop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"


    Dim ST As String = ComboBox1.SelectedText

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conectionstring)

    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT OBBALANCE FROM BALANCE WHERE CUSTOMERNAME =  " & " '" & ST & "'" & "", sqlcon)
    MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text)


    Dim result As Object

    Try
        sqlcon.Open()
        ' Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
        result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()

        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            TextBox1.Text = result.ToString()
            MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text)

        End If

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

i had done this but still i cant see the value in the textbox and obbalance is a flost value from the database sql

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub doSomething()
Dim conectionstring As String
        conectionstring = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SHOPPROJECT\SHOPPROJECT\shop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"


    Dim ST As String = ComboBox1.SelectedText

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conectionstring)

    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT OBBALANCE, CUSTOMERNAME FROM BALANCE" ,sqlcon)
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Try
        sqlcon.Open()
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()

        If sdr IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dt As DataTable
            dt.Load(sdr)

            With yourCombobox
                .DataSource = dt
                .DisplayMember = "CUSTOMERNAME"
                .ValueMember = "OBBALANCE"

            End With

        End If

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub comboBoxChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yourCombobox.SelectedIndexChanged

textbox.text = yourCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: I put your `SqlDataReader` into a `Datatable`. Then bound that `Datatable` to your combobox. Then in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for your `combobox` I added the code to grab the text from the `combobox` and place it into the `textbox`.

Comment: i have a database table in wich customer name and obbalance now wat i need is if i selecte the combobox the textbox should show the value of obbalce fothe selected customername from tat table now can u understand

Comment: That is what the `With End With` statement sets up. It is binding a `Datatable` column as the `DisplayMember` (CustomerName), and a column as the `ValueMember` (Obbalance) of your `ComboBox`. I updated the `SelectedIndexChanged` to grab the `value` from the `ComboBox` setting it as the `TextBox`'s text value.

Comment: Dim dt As DataTable
        dt.Load(objDataReader)
        With ComboBox1.SelectedItem
            .DataSource = dt
            .DisplayMember = dt "CUSTOMERNAME"//HERE IT SHOW ERROR END OF STATEMENT IS NOT CORRECT LIK THAT HOW TO WRTIE HERE
    .ValueMember = dt OBBALANCE
        End With
        TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString

Comment: SORRY TO DISTURB U AGAIN SIR can u edit my question and place this code where i have to place u r edited code its confussing me can u plz help it juz edit my question and place your code were it should be Sir please help me.........

Comment: Sir another thing i have already binded data to the combobox do i have to remove it  den i can use your code

Comment: I've update my post again. You might have to change the name of some controls to fit yours.

Comment: thx you so much you r the great and i am very thank full to you

Comment: sir can i have your mailid i have some more question i knw u can only help me

Comment: SIR I HAVE ONE DOUBT CAN WE USE A INSERTCOMMMAND AND ALSO A UPDATE COMMAND IN A SAME BUTTON CLICK OPERATION